# Priority in rospy loglevel configuration

Tags: ros, rospy, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy/Overview/Logging) show 2 ways to change log level of rospy; using `rospy.init_node` in code or using `$ROS_ROOT/config/python_logging.conf` file. I'm seeing with my system that when both ways are used, the code level config is dominant (meaning, setting in `python_logging.conf` is ignored). Am I correct? And if so, is there a way to make `python_logging.conf` reigns?

[Here](http://pastebin.com/0tVBWgbV) you can look at the `python_logging.conf` file I used , which I found at `/opt/ros/fuerte/etc/ros/python_logging.conf`, modified accordingly and moved to `$ROS_ROOT/config/`.

`fuerte`, Ubuntu 12.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46886/priority-in-rospy-loglevel-configuration/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2012-10-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-10-27**:
Good question; unfortunately I don't know the answer. But one quick comment: you shouldn't modify files under $ROS_ROOT; instead point the ROS_PYTHON_LOG_CONFIG_FILE environment variable to the location of your updated conf file, as described on the wiki page you linked to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe setting the logging level in code is always going to take precedence. As such you should rarely use it and only for temporary debugging.  Use the config file if you need it at startup or use rqt_logger_level to set it at runtime.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1